# scope_identity() in MsSql Server

Tags: sql-server

I get a null value when doing SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() After an insert.  Note that at the time I wrote the code, it worked like a charm.  The code is in classic ASP.

The query I use is :

```
INSERT INTO EID_Mandates([Uidx],[NatNr],[FirstName],[LastName],[ValidFrom],[ValidUntil],[Active]) 
VALUES(24387,'1234567','Paul','Tergeist','09/11/2015','09/11/2018',1);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As MYID
```

When executing, the Insert is OK, but no value returned (rs.fields.Count=0)

The Id is on the id_mandate field (auto increment).

I am puzzled !

---

EDIT : Nov, 10 - 10:56am.

Okay, after accepting the solution of CPMunich, I continued to search for the cause of the problem, because programming is not magic.  You expect logical result when using logical code.

What I discovered is even more frustrating.

1) the insertion code worked when I tested it, that is for sure, and no, I did not change anything to it.

2) I did some tests, namely using a simple script to check if Scope_Identity() was still working... Yes.

3) Then, I slightly modified my previous code to get through a test function which returned (and displayed the ID).  Nope, there was exactly 1 field, containing nothing (NULL).  In that very function I added the code to open another connection (the same code I use to open the main one).  Dang, it worked !

4) I logged the SQL produced in both cases.  Except the datetime and IDs, exactly the same.

So at this point, I know that my connection is somewhat corrupted, but have no idea why?

Finally I must add that the whole server had a big problem some month ago in the form of a rotten MS Update (KB2992611) which made the whole thing incredibly slow (this bug affected the way IIS connect via LSASS to MSSQL server.  In short, the server is 10 times slower for each and every query.

Not a problem, I am currently making all the work to migrate to another one.

Conclusion : unsure, sadly.  If I do new discoveries, I will keep you guys informed.

Thanks guys for your help, and StackOverflow for being there !

Remark : when you think to it, after all, PHP is also quite "ancient", no ?  :)

Comment: Are you sure that no one changed the column's identity definition?

Comment: How many record sets do you get back?  You have two statements, you may need to move to the next record set.  Also, did the insert succeed?  Are you sure you're not catching an error and ignoring it?  Have you tried this manually in SSMS?

Comment: make sure you are not closing SqlConnection and executing `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As MYID` in different SqlConnection

Comment: I only execute the statement as shown.  One insert only, the Scope_ID select being in the same query.

Comment: There are two distinct statements in your code block.  Of you had two SELECT statements then you'd intuitively expect two result sets.  I'm suggesting that your first empty set could belong to the first statement, and that until you iterate to the second result set you won't see the results you want.  I strongly suggest you show the asp code for us to check what you are doing.

Comment: Make sure you have not setup Insert Trigger for that table

Comment: What does IDENT_CURRENT()  return?If it returns the id your problems are session based

Comment: The first statement should not return anything.  I aslo tried this

Comment: INSERT INTO EID_Mandates([Uidx],[NatNr],[FirstName],[LastName],[ValidFrom],[ValidUntil],[Active]) VALUES(24387,'66101604756','Philippe','Huysmans','09/11/2015','09/11/2018',1)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As MYID
Fields : 1
ID=

Comment: OOps, I mean I tried to do it with two separates statement.  It shows a Rs.Fields.Count=1 but NOTHING in it.  Tried to retrieve it by name (MYID) or Rs(0).  Same thing.  Big void :)

Comment: And no there is no trigger in that db

Comment: I ***KNOW*** the insert returns nothing.  That's exactly why I'm saying you're getting nothing!!!  I'm saying you get two result sets; one with nothing, one with your identity value.  If you're using ADO, for example, you could use `rs.NextRecordSet` to move to the second record set, which I'm suggesting has what you want.  But if you can't be arsed even trying, if you want to ignore advice and stick to your old assumptions; Don't Ask Questions Here.  You still haven't even shown us your ASP code!

Comment: I had two distincts SQL statement separated by ; it is perfectly valid.  Moreover, I did try with two separate statements, the result is the same.  I got a NULL value.  All that is done on the SAME connection, still open.  No trigger.  And the code used to work !  ;(

Comment: `rs.fields.Count=0`? That hardly means you get a `NULL` value - it means you didn't get a value at all. How are you reading the result set? Have you checked if there are multiple result sets, as Mat suggested? Are you sure the identity column is still in place? Classic ASP is *ancient*, show the code you're using to read the results - there's plenty that could be subtly wrong.

Comment: The theorem demonstrating the infinity of primes is also ancient, and it still work.  I do not see the point.  In my last tests, rs.fields.count was 1 so yes, I will try to get trough the collection, just in case.  But no, it can't be wrong, it worked !

Comment: @MatBailie I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is an Option for you:

```
 INSERT INTO EID_Mandates([Uidx],[NatNr],[FirstName],[LastName],[ValidFrom],[ValidUntil],[Active]) 
 OUTPUT inserted.id_mandate
 VALUES(24387,'1234567','Paul','Tergeist','09/11/2015','09/11/2018',1);
```

You will get back a recordset with the column id_mandate. If the insert Fails, the recordset will be empty.

Comment: Your solution works, but sadly, I do not understand why the Scope_Identity() does not work here, even if it used to in the same code.  Thank you very much for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. Both statements are executed using same SqlCommand
2. You have not set up insert trigger for that table.

If you have setup insert trigger for that table use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`

Comment: `@@Identity` is problematic since it will return the last identity column value regardless of the scope or table. this might yield the wrong values.